# Hibernate - Student Grading System. Need help on annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, database-design, annotations, nhibernate-mapping

I'm working on a student information system using hibernate, where a student can have multiple courses (and marks). I want my POJOs like:

Student: `student attributes + Set<Course>`

Course: `course attributes + int marks`

But in database, I've following 3 tables.

```
create table STUDENT (
 STUDENT_ID BIGINT not null auto_increment primary key,
 // ... student type attributes
)

create table COURSE (
 COURSE_ID BIGINT not null auto_increment primary key,
 // ... course type attributes
)

create table STUDENT_COURSE_MARKS (
 STUDENT_ID BIGINT not null,
 COURSE_ID BIGINT not null,
 MARKS int default 0,
 CHECK (MARKS <= 100)
)
```

Questions:

1. Do I need to create one pojo per database table>
2. How can I set annotations to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public Class Student {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "student")
    private Set<StudentCourseMark> studentCourseMark = new HashSet<StudentCourseMark>(0);

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSE")
public Class Course {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "course")
    private Set<StudentCourseMark> studentCourseMark = new HashSet<StudentCourseMark>(0);

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT_COURSE_MARKS")
public Class StudentCourseMark {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID")
    private Course course;

    private List<Mark> marks = new ArrayList<Mark>(0);
}
```

Of course, you can use PrimaryKey on `STUDENT_ID`, `COURSE_ID` in your `StudentCourseMark`, here is example:
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

How to get Student marks:

```
Student student = getStudentFromDB();
List<Mark> marks = student.getMarks();
```

Comment: can there be something like Student pojo contains Set<Course> courses, and Course pojo contains int marks.?

Comment: On your schema MARK in STUDENT_COURSE_MARKS is only single field. Answer is edited but I used in StudentCourseMark list of marks.

Comment: Ideally Course object should hold marks, and Student should have set of courses. Please update database structure supporting this.

Comment: @masT You have right, my opinion is the same as your, but I worked on "existing" example.